# Swapping Components and Reversing Polarity

Tags: circuit-design, toggle-switch

I am having 2 DC motor, 2 Positive terminals & their negative Terminals. I want to build a circuit with 2 toggle switch so that when I toggle Both... It swaps the Motor and Change their polarity. That means

***Before Toggle,***

**Motor-1**

*Left*: +ve1
*Right*: -ve1

**Motor-2**

*Left*: -ve2
*Right*: +ve2

***After Toggle,***

**Motor-1**

*Left*: -ve2
*Right*: +ve2

**Motor-2**

*Left*: +ve1
*Right*: -ve1

I added an example so that it is easy for others to understand what I want. I tried to build the circuit but failed. Please Help.

Comment: What kind of toggle switches?

Comment: And what if you only operate 1 toggle switch - what do you expect to happen? What if both toggle switches (in different positions to start off with) are both reversed?

Comment: Both will be reversed

Comment: So if you toggle either or both, the motor directions will change?

Comment: Both motors spin in different directions yes? Your question text is somewhat ambiguous; you refer to motor 2 after a toggle as having +ve1 and -ve1 connections but, before the toggle you refer to motor 2 as having +ve2 and -ve2. This is really confusing.

Comment: Reversing both and both motors spin in diff direction

Comment: Are there any circumstances where motor 1 spins in the same direction as motor 2? Are there any circumstances where one motor is spinning and the other motor is not-spinning?

Comment: What does "left" and "right" refer to in the question?

Comment: That happens but I have different circuit for that in my project... So don't worry for that and don't even try to implement it.

Comment: Left and right are basically terminal 1 and terminal 2

Comment: So why not hard-wire both motors together so that they operate in different directions then, when you want to swap directions, you reverse their common supply voltage?

Comment: See... Explaining you that means telling and explaining my whole project... Which is not required

Comment: Then we are at the point when I vote to close the question as being unclear, sorry.

Comment: No... Wait I will tell you

Comment: I am making a battle not for my school project which is same upside down... I am not using microcontroller.... Only wires.. I am designing this circuit so that  even if my bot turns upside down I can reverse toggle and operate the bot as it is

Comment: @DhruvSinghal You haven't told me what I asked.

Comment: Any ways someone got it right... And gave answer per my requirements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strange and confusing set of requirements, but whatever, that is not for me to judge. You can do it with two break-before-make 2P2T toggle switches simply enough.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f35nLz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Just make sure the concept of break before make is well understood before doing it with actual switches and motors :)